# Magic college default skill in GURPS

Tags: magic, gurps, gurps-4e

Is there a way in GURPS to create a mage with a default level of skill in a specific magical college? I'm imagining something like an earth wizard who can attempt any earth college spell at a -3 penalty (since normally there is no default for magic).

I am particularly interested in GURPS 4e, but if there are solutions from other editions I would also like to hear them as I can probably make them work.

Comment: Which edition are you asking about?

Comment: I'm thinking about GURPS 4e in particular, but if there's any GURPS system answer I can probably make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the Ritual Magic system found on page 200 of GURPS Magic.

The features of the system are

- There is a base skill for example Thamuatology
- Each college of GURPS Magic is a IQ/VH skill defaulting off of the base skill. A college skill can't be raised higher than the base skill.
- Individual spells default off the college skill at a default equal to its prerequisite count. For example Ignite Fire is 0, and Fireball is 3. So if you have a skill of 14 in the Fire College you can cast Ignite Fire at 14 and Fireball at 11.
- Individual spells can be improved as techniques up to the level of the college skill.

The prerequisite count is found on the spell tables in the back of GURPS Magic.

Comment: This is the right answer... but if you want a more generic "any spell" type answer, there's always the "Magic!" (note the ! mark) "bang skill."

Answer (score 3):

For GURPS 4th edition, see Thaumatology p. 179 for syntactic magic and p.188 for Realms, which would cover a broad area of expertise like Earth.

It's not a default, per se, nor is it exactly collegiate magic, but I think it expresses the intention of what you are after pretty well.